# Django: How to check the view that renders a template

Tags: python, html, django

Want to know how to identify and output the view function that renders a template in HTML.
Need it for debugging purposes.

Something like this:

```
{% if request.view == "index" %}
    <title>Company Name</title>
{% else %}
    <title>{{ other_page_title }} &raquo; Company Name</title>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
{% if request.resolver_match.url_name == "index" %}
```

Comparing against the name given to the url in your `urls.py`, for example:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("home/", views.index, name="index"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using class-based views, you could add a `name` attribute to your view class, and then access it in your template.

```
class MyView(TemplateView):
    name = 'my_view'
```

You can access that in your template with `{{ view.name }}`.